# Basic ansible command-line fails with module failure error

Tags: ansible

My ansible command fails with error as below:

```
$ ansible all  -i /tmp/myhosts -m shell -a 'uname -a' -u user1 -k 
SSH password: 
host1.mycomp.com | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "", 
    "module_stdout": "  File \"/home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1556597037.27-168849792658772/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 39\r\n    with open(module, 'wb') as f:\r\n            ^\r\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 1
}
```

I do not know how to See stdout/stderr from single command line. Any suggestion how to view std out/err would be great.

```
$ more /tmp/myhosts
[mybox]
host1.mycomp.com
[dev]
host1.mycomp.com
[allserver:children]
mybox
dev
[allserver:vars]
variable=somestring
```

/tmp/hosts has good permissions.

I'm also able to ssh to the target server using the userid

```
$ ssh user1@host1.mycomp.com
Password: 
Last login: Tue Apr 30 00:03:57 2019 from 10.123.235.126
$ hostname
host1
```

```
ansible --version
2.7.1
```

Can you please help me overcome the error ?

Comment: The error is in your example: module_stdout. Maybe wrong Python version on the remote host?

Comment: Just as @ceving correctly pointed out, what you have is a copy of python2.6 on the remote host, which doesn't support the `with` syntax. You will want to either upgrade that python, or point the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable for that host to a 2.7 or greater (you can do that globally with `-e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2.7-or-whatever` or in your inventory for a specific host (or possibly group of them)

Comment: Rightly pointed out. Many Thanks !!